# Can a magnetic field hold a state of supercavitation if a magnetic field could be placed inside of the bubble of the supercavitation?

Tags: magnetic-fields, friction

I have a question that I am just curious about.

Two principles:

Magnetic fields and Magnetic susceptibility

[Supercavitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercavitation) is the use of cavitation effects to create a bubble of gas inside a liquid large enough to encompass an object traveling through the liquid, greatly reducing the skin friction drag on the object and enabling achievement of very high speeds.

Can a magnetic field hold a state of supercavitation if a magnetic field could be placed inside of the bubble of the supercavitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water and air are both weakly magnetic, with [magnetic permeabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29) on the order of $10^{-6}$ H/m whereas iron, a strongly magnetic material, has a permeability of about 0.25 H/m.

Thus, if you could create the supercavitation in water, a magnetic field would do just about nothing to maintain the cavity.

Comment: But, if you could keep the speed of the object constant so that the bubble stays, and you create the magnetic field with the actual object within the bubble of the superactivation, taking into account that there is also water surrounding both the magnetic material and the magnetic field, can the magnetic field exist within the moving air bubble and magnetic material?

Comment: As stated in my answer to your previous question, water (and air) will impede the magnetic field ever so slightly (on the order of 0.001%). Thus, the magnetic field can exist in the cavity (supposing, that is, it is somehow attached to the object moving)

Comment: That is exactly my thoughts as well.  This is what I think as well.  The object would have to be both in front and behind the object attached while moving.  You answered my question with what I was looking for.  On to my next questions.  Thank you Kyle.